# how to declare resources based on command line argument in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to test my code in different environments, test , prod ... I am planning to create a .env file and setting values for test and prod. but i have some declarations, line number 2 in sample below. i only need that when i run in local machine. how can i pass on an argument via command line, say main.py local and only then it executes at line else ignores it.

main.py

```
#connect to our cluster
1. from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

#local mode only
2. ec2 = boto3.Session(profile_name='dev', region_name='eu-west-1').client('ec2')


if __name__ = "__main__"
```

Comment: check out `sys.argv` inside the `sys` module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sys` library and `sys.args` like this:

```py
import sys

x = sys.argv[1]
print(x)
```

use `sys.argv[1]` not 0 because 0 is actually the filename

[image: Example]

Comment: thanks . I guess, we can check for this outside a python function too, right? like at the very top of the file?

Comment: yea, it doesn't change (the values of sys.argv)